# What is PEP8's E128: continuation line under-indented for visual indent?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, pep8

Just opened a file with Sublime Text (with Sublime Linter) and noticed a PEP8 formatting error that I'd never seen before. Here's the text:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', listing, name='investment-listing'),
)
```

It's flagging the second argument, the line that starts `url(...)`

I was about to disable this check in ST2 but ***I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong*** before I ignore it. You never know, if it seems important I might even change my ways :)

Comment: PEP8 does not have error messages; the linter does.

Answer (score 558, accepted):

[PEP-8 recommends](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) you indent lines to the opening parentheses if you put anything on the first line, so it should either be indenting to the opening bracket:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', listing, name='investment-listing'))
```

or not putting any arguments on the starting line, then indenting to a uniform level:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', listing, name='investment-listing'),
)

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '', url(r'^$', listing, name='investment-listing'))
```

I suggest taking a read through PEP-8 - you can skim through a lot of it, and it's pretty easy to understand, unlike some of the more technical PEPs.

Comment: I see! Yeah that makes sense. I've adopted this code from the "standard" Django way of doing things. I guess if I were writing something like this I would have put the first argument on its own line.

Comment: @Oli Yeah. I can understand the instinct to put the `''` on the first line, but it also makes it very easy to miss that it's there. The two styles in PEP-8 make it harder to skim past an argument when reading.

Comment: Anybody know why Django does this; is there a good reason? It seems that it would be just as easy to follow PeP-8.

Comment: @TheHerk I agree, and, as I mentioned in the comment above, I'd argue that doing it 'the django way' makes it easier to miss arguments. I imagine it's just a case of a style that someone picked and others followed.

Comment: This is so ubiquitous in Django code I've seen (plus it's all over their docs) that it arguably supersedes PEP-8, after all it says "*Many projects have their own coding style guidelines. In the event of any conflicts, such project-specific guides take precedence for that project.*"

Comment: @TheHerk the rationale is probably that the first argument to [`patterns()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#patterns) is unique (a prefix for everything else specified), and all the other arguments are url patterns which are basically the same.

Comment: @NickT I'd argue that if I didn't see that, and it took over a year for someone to comment on this saying that might be the reason, it's not a particularly clear way of showing that, if that's the intention. In general, I still think that it being easier to miss is reason enough to warrant the syntax PEP-8 recommends. Obviously if you were contributing to Django, follow their styles, for your own codebases, I'd avoid it if you can.

Comment: @Lattyware if you look at the Django docs, that is *exclusively* the formatting they use.  If you are using `patterns()` in your own projects, **PEP-8 recommends their formatting** because it is the *de facto* standard/convention for Django.

Comment: @NickT You are mis-reading PEP-8 - PEP-8 recommends following the existing convention where a given project uses it - but in this case the code is not going into Django, it's going into your project using Django - there is no need to follow their convention. The aim of that rule is to keep consistency inside code-bases.

Comment: Note that PEP8 also states that you should ignore PEP8 where it makes sense to do so, and I would argue that in this case in makes sense. Feel free to disagree for your own projects. In any case this will soon be a moot point as using `patterns()` will be deprecated in Django 1.8: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns

Comment: There is another case where it makes sense to ignore this rule. The indentation of `self` and `cls` in methods and `@classmethods` can be done similar way to reflect how many parameters will be passed into the function in case of a multi-line function declaration.

Comment: good tip to read through PEP-8.  It's clear and well-written. But it _is_ a long document: roughly 30 pages if printed...

Comment: @KaiCarver True, I'll change my wording a little: it doesn't take too long to go through because you can skim a lot of it (there are a lot of examples and stuff).

Answer (score 23):

This goes also for statements like this (auto-formatted by PyCharm):

```
    return combine_sample_generators(sample_generators['train']), \
           combine_sample_generators(sample_generators['dev']), \
           combine_sample_generators(sample_generators['test'])
```

Which will give the same style-warning. In order to get rid of it I had to rewrite it to:

```
    return \
        combine_sample_generators(sample_generators['train']), \
        combine_sample_generators(sample_generators['dev']), \
        combine_sample_generators(sample_generators['test'])
```

Comment: I highly prefer parenthesis over backslash here, first line being `return (`, then each returnable item on its own line, indented, and finally the closing bracket on a separate line, at the same indentation level as the `return`. **Edit:** Like this https://pastebin.com/fAe7558X

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Yes, me too. I just wanted to point out that not even the auto-format complies fully with this specification.