# How to make vim only insert 4 spaces (one indent level) for the next line after bracket when calling a function?

Tags: python, vim, indentation

After typing the bracket and enter, the next line will has 8 spaces indentation:

```
        print conn.generate_url(
                seconds,
                'GET',
```

instead of 4:

```
        print conn.generate_url(
            seconds,
            'GET',
```

My `~/.vimrc`: https://github.com/quantonganh/salt-states/blob/master/vim/vimrc.jinja2

Did I miss something?

Here's the list of my plugins:

```
├── ctrlp.vim
├── gundo.vim
├── jedi-vim
├── nerdtree
├── powerline
├── salt-vim
├── supertab
├── syntastic
├── ultisnips
├── vim-fugitive
├── vim-indent-guides
├── vim-surround
├── vim-yankstack
└── vundle
```

---

**UPDATE Sat Apr 12 10:00:55 ICT 2014**

I'm wondering that: is it follow [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) or not?

```
        print conn.generate_url(
                seconds,
                'GET',
                bucket,
                key,
                response_headers={
                    'response-content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
                })
```

> Continuation lines should align wrapped elements either vertically
>   using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets and
>   braces, or using a hanging indent. When using a hanging indent the
>   following considerations should be applied; there should be no
>   arguments on the first line and further indentation should be used to
>   clearly distinguish itself as a continuation line.

In a function, we will have something to distinguish with continuous lines, but here's just a `print`, should it be 4 or 8 spaces?

[What is PEP8's E128: continuation line under-indented for visual indent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435811/what-is-pep8s-e128-continuation-line-under-indented-for-visual-indent)

---

**UPDATE Sat Apr 12 23:09:27 ICT 2014**

Looks like `jedi-vim` doesn't do anything with Python's indentation. So my question should be change to something like:

It's OK to add 8 spaces (2 indent levels) for the next line after bracket when defining a function:

```
# More indentation included to distinguish this from the rest.
def long_function_name(
        var_one, var_two, var_three,
        var_four):
    print(var_one)
```

but I only want to add 4 spaces (one indent level) when calling it:

```
# Extra indentation is not necessary.
foo = long_function_name(
    var_one, var_two,
    var_three, var_four)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Yes, you missed adding the content of your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: I have added my `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @quanta, Did you ever get this to work? I'm dealing with a similar situation. Trying to conform to a specific project style guide. Only want 4 spaces indent on both cases though.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, [PEP8's chapter on indentation](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) suggests to add two indent levels instead of one before the arguments (when there is none on the first line) to distinguish it from the rest.

But it also adds that in cases where the extra indentation is not necessary, it's becomes optional. Your editor decided to add it, but according to PEP8, you have the choice.

Comment: I would like to add 8 spaces when defining a function but only 4 spaces when calling it. How can I do it?

Comment: I suppose you'll have to find which plugin manage the indentation and see if you can edit it to fit your needs. You can also juste manually remove the extra indentation. I don't know for vim, but most editors will keep the indentation of the previous line when creating an new one, so you only have to do this for the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Try `let g:pyindent_open_paren = 'shiftwidth()'` as per https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8757/how-to-set-the-relative-indent-after-breaking-python-lines. You can also use https://github.com/Vimjas/vim-python-pep8-indent for better indentation in general. This thread is also useful https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38823/how-to-set-gpython-indent-disable-parentheses-indenting