# PEP8 and initialization of object using long keyword arguments

Tags: python, argparse, pep8

It appears to me that there's no easy way to use the `RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` in the `argparse` module without either violating PEP8 or cluttering your namespace.

Here is the most obvious way to format it:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG',
                                 ....
                                 formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
```

This violates the stipulation that lines should not exceed 80 characters

Here's how the example in the `argparse` documentation looks (**spoiler: this is actually correct; see comments below**):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog='PROG',
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    ....
```

This violates PEP8 E128 regarding the indentation of continuation lines.

Here'another possibility:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog='PROG',
    formatter_class=
    argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    ....
```

This violates PEP8 E251 regarding spaces around `=` for keyward arguments.

(Of course, this doesn't even address the fact that my character-count for the line assumes that the `parser` token starts on the first column, which is the best case scenario; what if we want to create a parser inside a class and/or a function?)

So the only remaining alternative, as far as I can tell, is to either clutter the namespace:

```
from argparse import RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, ArgumentParser
```

...or use a silly temporary variable (which also clutters the namespace):

```
rawformatter = argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG',
                                 ....
                                 formatter_class=rawformatter)
```

Am I missing something? I guess having RawDescriptionHelpFormatter and ArgumentParser directly in the current namespace isn't a big deal, but this seems like an unnecessary frustration.

Comment: How does the `argparse` example violate E128? If you put any arguments on the first line, the subsequent arguments have to be indented to match; if you don't, they have to be indented one step in. The latter is exactly what the `argparse` example does. It's identical to the "# Hanging indents should add a level" example in [PEP 8 itself](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). The `pep8` checker, and the other two linters I have lying around, both agree. So, what makes you think it's bad?

Comment: @abarnert Ah. It doesn't. In my actual example file on which I was running a PEP8 checker, I had arguments on the first line. Stupid mistake, but I'm glad I asked here.

Comment: I think this question should be closed, but I gave the wrong close reason. This is a "can no longer be reproduced or was a simple typo" case, not an "unclear what you're asking" question. It _is_ clear, it's just not asking about the right code, and if it were, you would have already known the answer…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example looks fine to me, and seems to match the "# Hanging indents should add a level." example here: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Also seems to tally with this similar question/answer: [What is PEP8's E128: continuation line under-indented for visual indent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435811/what-is-pep8s-e128-continuation-line-under-indented-for-visual-indent)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of other variations:

```
from argparse import RawDescriptionHelpFormatter as formatter

parser = argparse.ArgumentFormatter(prog='PROG')
# you can reassign a parser attribute after initialization
parser.formatter_class = formatter
```

But there are other inputs to `ArgumentParser` that may be long enough to require wrapping or assignment to separate variables.

```
usage = 'PROG [-h] --foo FOO BAR etc'
description = """\
This is a long multiline description
that may require dedenting.
"""
description = textwrap.dedent(description)
parser=Argparse(usage=usage, description=description, formatter_class=formatter)
```

Take a look at `test_argparse.py` to see the many ways that a long and multifaceted parser can be defined.

---

http://bugs.python.org/issue13023 raises the issue of what if you wanted several formatter modifications, e.g.:

> This means we can either pass argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter or argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, but not both.

The recommended solution is to subclass the formatter:

```
class MyFormatter(argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, 
    argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpformatter):
    pass
```

Another tactic to keep the namespace clean is to wrap the parser definition in a function or module.

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magic_arguments.html

is an example of how `IPython` wraps `argparse` to make new API for its users.

Another parser built on `argparse`, `plac` first builds a `cfg` dictionary:

https://code.google.com/p/plac/source/browse/plac_core.py

```
def pconf(obj):
    ...
    cfg = dict(description=obj.__doc__, 
               formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    ...
    return cfg

def parser_from(obj, **confparams):
    ...
    conf = pconf(obj).copy()
    conf.update(confparams)
    parser = ArgumentParser(**conf)
```

Comment: Your second code block has a >=80-char line, and doesn't demonstrate wrapping, and you've also got a string with broken continuations that will raise a `SyntaxError` (and that should have been written as a triple-quoted string), plus at least one other exception (a `NameError`). But, most importantly, I can't figure out what it's supposed to be showing.

Comment: @abarnert I think hpaulj's point is that it's frequently a good idea to assign `usage` and `description` to separate variables, which is true. In any case, +1 for pointing out that the `formatter_class` can be assigned after initialization.

Comment: Opps, I meant to use triple quotes.

Comment: I added a few more examples of complicated `ArgumentParser` definitions.

Comment: Dang. You've got the seed of a decent `argparse` tutorial here. You should write one up and post it somewhere.