# PEP8 E128: can't figure out why a line is being flagged

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, pep8

I'm using Sublime + [Anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) which has a built-in PyLint feature.

I can't figure out why the `pars_f_name)` line in the following block:

```
            else:
                # Get parameters file name from path.
                pars_f_name = pars_f_path.split('/')[-1]
                print ("  WARNING: Unknown '{}' ID found in line {}\n"
                       "  of '{}' file.\n").format(reader[0], l + 1,
                       pars_f_name)

# Pack params in lists.
pl_params = [flag_make_plot, plot_frmt, plot_dpi]
```

is being flagged as:

```
[W] PEP 8 (E128): continuation line under-indented for visual indent
```

I've tried every indentation I could think of (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435811/what-is-pep8s-e128-continuation-line-under-indented-for-visual-indent)) but Anaconda keeps flagging that line as a PEP8 E128 warning.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to further indent the `str.format()` arguments:

```
print ("  WARNING: Unknown '{}' ID found in line {}\n"
       "  of '{}' file.\n").format(reader[0], l + 1,
                                   pars_f_name)
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As a personal choice, I'd put those arguments all on one line, indented:

```
print ("  WARNING: Unknown '{}' ID found in line {}\n"
       "  of '{}' file.\n").format(
           reader[0], l + 1, pars_f_name)
```

This is called a [*hanging indent*](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#fn-hi).

See the [*Indentation* section](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) of PEP 8; these considerations apply recursively to each nested call expression.

Comment: I'd still line the parens up; but oh well! Personal choice and all :)

Comment: @JamesMills: I'm 50/50 on putting the parentheses around the whole `str.format()` operation, but I tend to gather my closing parentheses on the same line. :-)

Comment: Thank you Martijn! This was driving me crazy, I hadn't noticed I also had to indent the `format()` argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah fair enough :) It's quite subjective really! Still a +1 form me :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
print ("  WARNING: Unknown '{}' ID found in line {}\n"
                   "  of '{}' file.\n").format(reader[0], l + 1,
                   pars_f_name)
```

with:

```
print(
    "  WARNING: Unknown '{}' ID found in line {}\n"
    "  of '{}' file.\n".format(
        reader[0], l + 1, pars_f_name
    )
)
```

It's basically complaining about the lack of indentation for the `str.format()` part; but formatting your code as per the above example makes it far more readable!

**Update:** This is called "hanging indent" in PEP8 (*See: @MartijnPieters's response*) This response is more of "here's how to fix it and make it readable at the same time". (*unfortunately there are many competing subjective opinions on this though!*)

Comment: Not sure why this answer got downvoted. I prefer Martijn's formatting but +1 for providing an explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @Gabriel I'm not sure either; both are quite valid approaches but there are different ways to solve the same "hanging indent" issue with PEP8 compliance.