# Python - PEP8 hanging indent error message

Tags: python-3.x, pep8

For the following code I am getting the below error:

```
config = {
    'bucket': json.loads(record['body'])
                ['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'],
    'key': json.loads(record['body'])
           ['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
}
```

```
E131 continuation line unaligned for hanging indent
                              ['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'],

E131 continuation line unaligned for hanging indent
                           ['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
```

I have tried a few options including the below - but it is not working:

```
config = {
    'bucket': json.loads(
                        record['body']
                        )
                        ['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'],
    'key': json.loads(record['body'])
           ['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
}
```

I have also tried `+ \` at the end of the line but does not work also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To conform with PEP8, the below worked for this scenario:

```
config = {
    'bucket': json.loads(record['body'])
    ['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'],

    'key': json.loads(record['body'])
    ['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the best way, I just check with my IDE. Just get the same result as much as like you answer.

Comment: This may conform to PEP8, but the real hint here should be to store `json.loads(record['body'])['Records'][0]['s3']` in a variable, since it is duplicate and contains a parsing-step. This is actually not very readable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it should be either this format

```py
config = {
    'bucket': json.loads(record['body'])['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'],
    'key': json.loads(record['body'])['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
}
```

or in this,

```py
config = {
    'bucket': json.loads(record['body']) \
                ['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'],
    'key': json.loads(record['body']) \
           ['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
}
```

For more information, please check [What is PEP8's E128: continuation line under-indented for visual indent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15435811/6194097) question.

Comment: Thanks. For option 1, I have `max_line_length` of 79 so would not be an option. For option 2 `\` was redundant between brackets. I have found an answer and will post that.