# continuation line under-indented for visual indentflake8(E128)

Tags: python, flake8

I am editing Python code and my flake8 linter is complaining (see red squiggly line on line 842) about my indentation here
[image]

The specific error is

```
continuation line under-indented for visual indentflake8(E128)
```

Based on my understanding, line 842, because it is a continuation, should start at the character right after the opening parenthesis, which is what is happening here, so why is it still complaining?

Comment: Try adding a `\\` at the end of line 841

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435811/what-is-pep8s-e128-continuation-line-under-indented-for-visual-indent)